# Mysql where from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables called Product and Category

Product

```
id        name           category        
1         Product #1     1           
2         Product #2     1               
3         Product #3     1               
4         Product #4     2
```

Category

```
id        name                  
1         Category #1              
2         Category #2                 
3         Category #3                 
4         Category #4
```

How would I call all products where Category #1 is true? Essential use the actually name instead of the number so that mysql would see that category.name = category.id and then call all the products based on that.

Comment: Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) and get back to us if you have any problems

Comment: Or http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php and http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Join:

```
SELECT * FROM products AS p 
 LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON p.category = c.id 
 WHERE c.name LIKE 'Category #1'
```

Comment: Technically, I think you'd want an inner join here, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
      P.*
   from
      Category C
         JOIN Products P
            on C.ID = P.Category
   where
      C.Name = 'Category #1'
```

This way, it immediately STARTS with your category table by its name, then goes to products that match the by the proper internal ID link reference.